org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot change ownership of identity sequence
After migrating to Spring Boot 3.3.2 and Hiernate 6.5.2, I am getting below error (for my liquibase script) while executing my test cases.
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [changeset/[obfuscated]-create-table.sql]: ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq OWNED BY public.[table_name].id
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282)
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot change ownership of identity sequence
  Detail: Sequence "id_seq" is linked to table "[table_name]".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725)
    ...



But the same script was working fine in Spring Boot 3.1.11 and Hibernate 6.2
I am not getting enough content related to this error, Is there any changes that are introduced into the new versions?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please add relevant part of changeset/[obfuscated]-create-table.sql script and/or liquibase script.
